Which collection should I put new objects into?
I notice that, with factory-default settings, blender starts with two collections:

A top-level "Scene Collection", which apparently can't be renamed or deleted
A child collection "Collection", containing a Camera, Cube, and Light.
This child collection can be renamed or deleted.


Initially, bpy.context.scene.collection is set to the top-level "Scene Collection", whereas bpy.context.collection is set to the child "Collection"
(but changes if the user clicks on a different collection in the outliner;
in general it is the "active collection", i.e. the one whose icon has a transparent outline
around it in the outliner).
When I create a new object using bpy.data.objects.new() (lower level than bpy.ops), it seems I then need to add the new object to one of the existing collections, in order to make it visible.  Which collection?
The likely candidates seem to be:
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(my_new_object)

or:
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(my_new_object)

Evidence in favor of bpy.context.scene.collection (the top-level collection called "Scene Collection"):

that's what it says in many examples, e.g. https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/2.80/python_api/scene_and_object_api/#adding-objects
that's apparently where Import->glTF puts new objects.

Evidence in favor of bpy.context.collection (the active collection: the one named "Collection" initially):

that's apparently where the Add menu (and bpy.ops) puts new objects.

Is there a policy/guideline/rationale for deciding which collection to put new objects into?
To be clear, the cases I'm asking about are the cases in which I don't have any opinion about the overall structure of the scene (when I do have an opinion, of course I'll just put the new object where I want it to go).  E.g. the cases in question are when I'm writing an importer, or an addition to the Add -> Mesh menu, or some other utility function along the lines of either of those two (similar-seeming, to me) cases.  If I try to follow precedent, I seem to get two contradictory conclusions, thus my question.
Please note that this is not a duplicate of question Collection for New Object? (Version 2.8) , which asks only which collection the Add menu puts new objects into when using the UI.

Hello, IMO this is an opinion-based question because both propositions are valid, and depend on your end goal. You can even link your object to both collections. Or none, which will create an orphaned object but nonetheless a valid object. You may want to add more information about the broader picture and what you are trying to achieve here with this script ? BTW the question is exceptionally well formatted, I wanted to point it out.

@Gorgious Thanks.  In the cases for which I'm asking the question, I'm writing, say, an importer, or an addition to the "Add -> Mesh" menu, or something in-between-ish feeling, which is why I gave those two examples (with contradictory conclusions if I want to try to follow precedent... thus my question!).  I.e. my code creates object(s) to be used by other code (maybe in direct response to the user pressing a button or selecting a menu item, maybe less directly) but my code doesn't itself care about the overall structure of the scene.

@Gorgious I added a paragraph attempting to clarify the situations for which I'm asking the question.

I'm coming around to the conclusion that I have fallen victim to the "I have to put it in some collection, otherwise it won't be visible" fallacy.  No, I don't have to put it in any collection, because no, I don't have to make the object visible (and in fact I shouldn't, when, say, the code is at roughly the same low level of decision-making as bpy.data.objects.new()).    I'll write up an answer summarizing my current thoughts and conclusions.

I added an answer/proposal that resolves all the considerations I had been wondering about.

Tl;DR: if in doubt, Scene Collection.
I don't think it matters as much as you seem to think. Scene collection just serves as container for all objects and collections in the current scene. Any other collection is whatever the user wants.
You need to register your object in at either the scene's collection or a collection of that scene for it to appear in that particular scene (you could assign it to another scene this way, or to no scene at all and have it floating in your blend file for nothing).
So if you want your object in a particular collection, out it there. If not, default to the scene collection, or whatever you like.

Hi @Lauloque, yes certainly if I want an object to go in a particular collection I'll put it there, and I'll make new collections to hold the new items if it makes sense.    This would be the case if my intent is to construct a scene and I specifically want the structure of the scene to be a certain way.  But in the cases I'm not sure of (and why I'm asking the question), I don't have an opinion about the structure of the scene, I'm just trying to write clean modules/utilities, e.g. an importer or an addition to the Add menu, or something in-between-ish.

As long as you label it for what it is (e.g., "Add Object to Currently Selected Collection"), it should be fine. Even if it weren't explicitly stated, such a small detail probably wouldn't matter too much to the user.

I'm proposing this answer, after more thought and considering the comments and answer given so far.  These are the guidelines I'm now following.  I'd welcome any feedback, particularly if I got any facts wrong or missed any relevant information that should be considered.
TL;DR: Put the decision of what collection to use at the appropriate level of code, at which the choice either is obvious, or is an artistic decision of authorship of the scene structure, being made by that code.  If your code is at such a low level that it doesn't care, then don't put the new object in any collection.
Details and rationale:

If you're writing code that cares about where the new object goes, then of course put it there.  This would be the case if, say, your code is constructing a scene and is deciding the hierarchical structure of that scene.

Otherwise, if you're writing a function to be called more-or-less directly as a user action (e.g. an importer, or an addition to the Add -> Mesh menu), then follow the precedent of what bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add() and all the other bpy.ops functions called by those menu items do: add the new object to the active collection, i.e. bpy.context.collection.  This allows the user to have convenient control of where new objects go, by clicking the desired collection in the outliner to make it active (denoted by the transparent circle around the icon).


Note that the glTF importer does not follow the guideline stated in the previous paragraph: it apparently ignores the active collection, and instead puts new objects under the scene's top-level collection.  This may be due to it trying to satisfy a contradictory goal-- that is, to turn each of the things called "scenes" in the glTF file into the things called "scenes" in Blender.  At this point I'm not familiar enough with any other importers to know whether they are in a similar situation and/or have similar behavior.

If you're not in either of the above two cases, then you probably don't care where the object goes in the scene, if anywhere.  E.g. maybe you're writing a utility function that creates a new mesh object, to be used by other higher-level calling code.  In that case, don't put the new object in any collection-- let the calling code make the decision of where to put it, if anywhere.  This follows the precedent of bpy.data.objects.new() (which you are likely calling in your function).

Don't be tempted to helpfully add the new object to bpy.context.scene.collection, or anywhere else, just "because it's not visible until I do".  While it's true that code that calls bpy.data.objects.new() is prone to forgetting altogether to link the new object into any collection (resulting in questions on mailing lists and on this site), the "solution" of adding the object to an arbitrary collection actually creates a bigger problem than the one it solves: it makes it so that caller has to go out of its way to unlink the new object from that collection if it doesn't want that link.  This is one of several automagical side effects of the bpy.ops functions that make them painful to use by higher-level functions, making many experienced programmers prefer to avoid them.
